Validation accuracy going over 100% in Pytorch?
I am currently doing a project where I am attempting to correctly classify images of breast cancer tumors to predict if they are benign (ok) or malignant (dangerous) for which I am using Pytorch. I have set up my network which extends the ResNet18 model and added a few more layers. For the hyperparameters, I originally set them up myself but wanted to use a method such as random search to find the best hyperparameters. However, upon running the validation loop pipeline to get the accuracy, I find it is going over 100%?
I load in my data like so:

import torch.utils
import torch.utils.data
from torchvision.transforms import transforms
import torch.utils.data as data

transformed_data = transforms.Compose([ # using Compose() to chain data transformations
    transforms.ToTensor()
])



training_dataset = DataSetClass(split="train", transform=transformed_data, download=download)
# testing_dataset = DataSetClass(split="test", transform=transformed_data, download=download)

train_size = int(training_ratio * len(training_dataset))
validation_size = int(validation_ratio * len(training_dataset))
testing_size = len(training_dataset) - train_size - validation_size

train_set, validation_set, testing_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(
    training_dataset, [train_size, validation_size, testing_size]
)

# convert data into dataloader form
train_loader = data.DataLoader(dataset=train_set, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
validation_loader = data.DataLoader(dataset=validation_set, batch_size=2*BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False)
test_loader = data.DataLoader(dataset=testing_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False)


print(training_dataset)
print("=======================")
print(testing_dataset)

I attempted to create a list storing different values for each hyperparameter as shown below along with performing the validation loop:
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np

# Define your hyperparameters space
lr_space = [0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05]
epochs_space = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
batch_size_space = [32, 64, 128, 256]

# Initialize your network
network = ExtendedNetwork(resnet18)
network.to(device=device)

# Define your loss function
loss_function = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

network.eval()

best_accuracy = 0
best_hyperparameters = None
validation_accuracy = 0


# Perform random search
for _ in range(100): 
    lr = np.random.choice(lr_space)
    epochs = np.random.choice(epochs_space)
    batch_size = np.random.choice(batch_size_space)

    # Use the selected hyperparameters to train your model
    optimizer = optim.Adam(network.parameters(), lr=lr)
    
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        with torch.no_grad():
            for inputs, targets in validation_loader:
                inputs, targets = inputs.to(device), targets.to(device)

                # Forward
                output = network(inputs)

                # Calculate and accumulate accuracy
                validation_accuracy += accuracy(output, targets)

        # Calculate average accuracy over all validation batches
        validation_accuracy /= len(validation_loader)

        print('Validation accuracy:', validation_accuracy)

        # If the current model is better than all previous models, update the best accuracy and best hyperparameters
        if validation_accuracy > best_accuracy:
            best_accuracy = validation_accuracy
            best_hyperparameters = {'lr': lr, 'epochs': epochs, batch_size': batch_size}

print('Best accuracy:', best_accuracy)
print('Best hyperparameters:', best_hyperparameters)

This leads to results:
Validation accuracy: 0.045871559633027525
Validation accuracy: 0.09174311926605505
...
Validation accuracy: 135.73394495412717
Validation accuracy: 135.77981651376018

Best accuracy: 135.77981651376018
Best hyperparameters: {'lr': 0.03, 'epochs': 40, 'batch_size': 256}

But the accuracy should be capped at 100% ? I do not understand if my error is coming from the way I am loading my data or the validation loop pipeline
Edits:

Moved the validation_accuracy inside the epoch (which I did before but am still getting a constant accuracy which is neither increasing or decreasing, something like "Validation accuracy: 0.3761467889908257"

Could it be due to the way I am using the batch size I set myself and using it in the loader variables such as train_loader, validation_loader, test_loader but then I am wanting to use a list of batch sizes? Should i be using the values from batch_size_space inside the loaders instead?



What is batch_size corresponding to? It is not being used in your code.

@Ivan that is what I am trying to figure out..

What do you mean? You defined batch_size in your code, what is the point of that? Is it your code?

You should reset validation_accuracy to 0 at the start of every epoch.

Hi, I did try this but then my accuracy just stays constant and does not increase and constantly shows something like:
Validation accuracy: 0.3761467889908257

This is a learning problem then. Have you tried to overfit a small batch of data?

Yes, I believe the problem is that overfitting is occuring. Should I increase my batch size would you say? I am using the breastmnist dataset

Oh and also if you look at the edits section of my post, I believe that is an issue but I am not sure on how to solve it?
